# How to autocomplete input in field Django

Tags: python, django

I have a product model. I need to autocomplete product name into input field. How can I code?

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product_detail = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    product_price = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures/%Y/%m/%d/', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    product_amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    del_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

Comment: On type you need to be querying db and filtering user input with your data in the columns, This is best done with ajax call

Comment: check out Django-autocomplete-light, i found it very useful.

Comment: Django-autocomplete-light can use in admin page only, right? I need to implement it on my site.